# How to apply a format in a DataView row filter?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, rowfilter

I want to search through my DataTable as I used to with SQL. I am trying to make the row filter ignore numbers that fit these formats: '123-4567-000' or 'SK1234-F1234' ... Here is my current query:

```
DataView1.RowFilter = "Number NOT LIKE '___-____-___' AND Number NOT LIKE '______-_____'"
```

Although, the row filter as such will still return results where the number looks like this: `450-0034-00X` or `350-3303-04B` and etc. I don't want these results to show up (hence the NOT LIKE).

SQL can currently apply this query and omit results that would normally contain the format mentioned above.

---

### Example

Below is a list of numbers in my Dataview. Using the format with the row filter, two of them would be omitted and my result set would contain only 4 out of the 6 numbers.

```
4500
340034
44393
450-3403-00X 'Should not show up
34321
SK1234-F1234 'Should not show up
```

How can I recreate that in a DataView's row filter? Is it possible to apply a format with a row filter?

Comment: can you give an example of the format you *do* want to show up?

Comment: @Plutonix Done, let me know if I can make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to the problem but any other solutions are welcomed!

For example, the numbers who are similar to '450-3403-00X' will get omitted using this query:

```
"NOT (substring(Number,4,1)= '-' AND substring(Number,9,1)= '-')"
```

This simply verifies if we have a dash at position 4 and position 9 ... Makes it work!

Still very curious if there are other ways to accomplish this.